# How to Print components div using Cordova Printer plugins

Tags: cordova, vue.js, printing, cordova-plugins, quasar-framework

Please I need help with identifying while I cannot print using Cordova printer plugins with this code.

```
printReport () {
      var newstr = document.getElementById('analysis').innerHTML
      var div = document.createElement('div')
      div.className = 'listPrint'
      div.innerHTML = this.getIngredientList()
      const prtHtml = '<h4>ShoopiShopping List</h4>'
      let styleHtml = ''
      for (const node of [...document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"], style')]) {
        styleHtml += node.outerHTML
      }
      const winPrint = window.open('')
      winPrint.document.write(`<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>ShopIt</title>
        ${styleHtml}
        </head>
        <body>
        ${prtHtml}`
      )
      winPrint.document.body.append(div)
      winPrint.document.write(`${newstr}`)
      winPrint.document.write(`</body>
        </html>`)
      cordova.plugins.printer.print(winPrint)
    }
```

My intention is to print two different sections of the page. One section is printed as it is, using innerHTML, while the list of items from the second section is used to form a table using **this.getIngredientList()**

On initiating print, the app generate a document with required information for printing accurately, but no printer dialog shows up.

Please, what am I not doing right?

**UPDATE**

I changed to

```
winPrint.cardova.plugins.printer.print()
winPrint.close()
```

And it displays print dialog and prints. 
However, winPrint.close() is not executed. the generated page by winPrint= window.open() remain opened and I have to forced the app to exit.

Answer (score 0):

although, I haven't figure out the why **window.close()** refused to be called/executed, this is what I do eventually,

```
    const winPrint = (`<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>ShopIt</title>
            ${styleHtml}
            </head>
            <body>
            ${prtHtml}`
          )

     cordova.plugins.printer.print(winPrint, { name: 'report' })
```

I hope this helps someone.